# python - same instruction, different outcome

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could someone help me understand what is going on in the following Python code (python 3.2)? I'm really clueless here.

```
import sys
u = sys.stdin.readline()
   # try entering the string "1 2 3" 
r = map(lambda t: int(t.strip()),u.split())
print(sum(r)) # prints 6
print(sum(r)) # prints 0 ?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`map()` in Python 3.x returns an iterator, not a list. Putting it through `sum()` the first time consumes it, leaving nothing for the second time.

Comment: To add to this answer: If you want to keep the results as a list, do `r = list(map(...))` instead.

Comment: @kindall actually, a list comprehension would probably be cleaner

Comment: That's certainly true. Of course it would have been cleaner to use in the first place.  :-)

Comment: Thank you for a lightningspeedfast reply.